# Infinite microstates

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

The concept of number of microstates makes sense for something like magnetisation where each electron has an up or down spin, so we can use counting arguments.

But then they extend this logic to two gas boxes in thermal contact with each other and say that there must be some macrostate with the maximum number of microstates and then use calculus to derive an expression for temperature at equilibrium. But the issue I am having is that energy, atleast classically is a continuous thing, so don’t we have uncountably infinite microstates for each macrostate? Then how does it make sense to compare the number of microstates?

Comment: You associate a certain phase space volume to a macro state.

Comment: Sorry I haven’t learnt phase space yet, I am in undergrad. Do I just equate this to saying that we assume a small range of energies to be one state and discretise it like that? Thank you